# Counterexample in Kolmogorov theorem about existence of almost surely continuous modification

Tags: stochastic-processes, counterexamples, expectation

I want to understand this Kolmogorov theorem about existence of almost surely continuous modification:

  A process $\{\xi_t, \in[0,T]\}$ admits an almost surely continuous modification if there exist constants $a,b,c>0$ such that $$\mathbb{E}[|\xi_t-\xi_s|^a]\leq b|t-s|^{1+c}$$ for all $s,t\in [0,T]$. 

 
And I have such a question. What if we take a process $\{\xi_t=e^{w_t^3}, t\in[0,T]\}$, where $w_t$ is  standard wiener process. How can I show nonexistence of $\mathbb{E}[|\xi_t-\xi_s|^a]$ for any $a$?

Comment: I think the idea is that there is a probability of something like $\exp(-M/(t-s)^2)$ that $W_t$ and $W_s$ differ by more than $2M$. This ensures that $|\xi_t-\xi_s|>e^{M^3}$, so $|\xi_t-\xi_s|>e^{aM^3}$. Since the value of the random variable grows faster than the probability decreases, this ensures that the expectation is infinite.